# How to read a sepearte line from a text file using python

Tags: python-2.7

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [l for l in lines if "util.exe" in l]
with open("Lines.txt", "w") as f1:
    new=f1.writelines(lines)
```

This is my example code to write a line which are having the text "util.exe".But i need to read a line which is below in ""util.exe" line.

For Example i have a text file with these lines.

```
1/16 joc_... 

cd D:\cmd\find\joc

util.exe line
```

pcm wav line I need to read

Here I need to read a line `pcm wav line i need to read` which is below in `util.exe line`

Can you please guide me for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggested solution. Just modify your list comprehension by enumerating the lines and then accessing the line after the util.exe. So here is modified code:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [lines[index + 1] for index, l in enumerate(lines) if "util.exe" in l]
with open("Lines.txt", "w") as f1:
    new=f1.writelines(lines)
```

So when I run the modified script here are the results:
Contents of example

"file.txt" -->

```
this is a test line
and here is another one
util.exe is here
this one should be recorded
but this one should not
now it appears at the end util.exe
this should also be saved. finally,
another case
the test phrase util.exe is in the middle
where this should be saved
but not this one
```

This is the output file "Lines.txt":

```
this one should be recorded
this should also be saved. finally,
where this should be saved
```

Answer (score 0):

```
destLines = []
with open("file.txt") as fp:
   lines = fp.readlines()
   index = 0
   for line in lines:
      index += 1
      if 'exe' in line and len(lines) >= index:
          destLines.append(lines[index])

with open("lines.txt", "w") as fp:
     fp.writelines(destLines)
```

Comment: Actually i need to read  a line which is under "exe".that is below line..